# Copy & Paste folded Code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy-paste, folding

When I copy folded code it just pastes the beginning line (that's visible).

For example if I copy this code when it's folded:

```
Expanded(
  flex: 2,    
  child: Image(
    image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),
  ),
),
```

It will just paste the starting code:

```
Expanded(
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to select also the end of the folded range to successfully copy all the folded content.

See this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58209).

A workaround could be to add this line in settings.json:

```
"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
```

That would make visible that ending range making it possible for you to select up to it and including it.

Answer (score -1):

in Visual Studio Code
just press ( Ctrl + Shift + [ ) to fold  code and  ( Ctrl + Shift + Down ) to selected code.
and then copy selected code ( Ctrl + c ).

in mac:
Command = ctrl
Options = alt